# Trim input values before express-validator in Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express-validator

I'm using the suggested V4 syntax of express-validator in a Node.js project:

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');
const { matchedData } = require('express-validator/filter');
```

and

```
app.post('/users/add/',[
check('first_name')
.isLength({ min: 1 }).withMessage('A first name is required')],
(req, res, next) => {
  var errors = validationResult(req);
  if (errors) {
     ..etc
```

Note that I am using the modern syntax and do not have the following code (as 
per the express-validator README.md file):

```
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
app.use(expressValidator());
```

How do I trim blank spaces from the input field before running the validation?

Comment: As of v4.1.1, sanitization is only available in the legacy APIs, but please open an issue in the GitHub tracker requesting support in the new APIs.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `.trim()` before your `.check()` like this,

```
check('first_name').trim().isLength({ min: 1 }).withMessage('A first name is required')]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sanitization is only available in the legacy APIs for now

Comment: This is now available starting with v4.2.0 :)

Answer (score 0):

The following work around may help, though I think the best solution would be to support sanitation in a fluent manner.  The downside of my work around is that the processing of input is now in two places.

1. Add the required sanitation functions to requires clause:

   ```
   const { trim } = require('express-validator').validator
   ```
2. Adjust the request processing:

   ```
   app.post('/users/add/',
    (req, res, next) => {
   req.body.first_name = trim(req.body.first_name);
   req.body.last_name = trim(req.body.last_name);
   req.body.email = trim(req.body.email);
   next();
   },
   [check('first_name')
   .isLength({ min: 1 }).withMessage('A first name is required')],
   (req, res, next) => {
    var errors = validationResult(req);
    if (errors) {
   ..etc
   ```